# Swapping array dimensions with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

When I load an image with PIL and convert it into a NumPy array:

```
image = Image.open("myimage.png")
pixels = np.asarray(image)
```

The data is stored as [x][y][channel]. I.e., the value of pixels[3, 5, 0] will be the the (3, 5) pixel, and the red component of that pixel.

However, I am using a library which requires the image to be in the format [channel][x][y]. Therefore, I am wondering how I can do this conversion?

I know that NumPy has a `reshape` function, but this doesn't actually allow you to "swap" over the dimensions as I want.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `transpose` method as opposed to the `reshape` method

Comment: There's swapaxes, rollaxis, and transpose. All of them allow you to permute axes in one way or another.

Answer (score 7):

In order to get the dimensions in the order that you want, you could use the transpose method as follows:

```
image = Image.open("myimage.png")
pixels = np.asarray(image).transpose(2,0,1)
```